# FCM custom sound notifications are not working on IOS Xcode

Tags: flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging, apple-push-notifications

I'm developing a Flutter application for both Android and IOS. I'm sending to my users custom sound notifications using Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM).

On Android everything is just fine, I'm receiving notifications with custom sounds. However, on IOS I'm receiving the notifications, but with default sound.

I have configured my `Xcode` as the following:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your sound files should be plain directly to the `Copy Bundle Resources` (and not in the `assets` folder).

[image]

Comment: thanks for replying. Just making sure, you are saying that I need to attach each sound file to the `Copy Bundle Resources` individually? (and not under the assets folder).

Comment: yes, exactly. .xcassets folders are used for colors and images mainly. They are referenced differently than Bundle files, so the sound files should not be inside the .xcassets

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will verify your answer at the upcoming days and will update the accepted answer accordingly :)

Comment: I have tested your answer, it worked! The problem was that I located the sound files in folders, instead of put them directly in the `Copy Bundle Resources`. Thanks!